# Data from Power Query not matching once referenced in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, dax, powerquery

I have a Power Query connection that is loaded to the local data model so that the data can be referenced in Excel formulas. When I reference that data in a formula , "=MAX(PayrollDates)", the data returned does not match the data shown when editing the query.
[image: Excel Output]

Data returned from formula is "45688" or "1/31/2025" where the table in the data model and the PQ is "45345" or "2/23/2024", depending on data type set in PQ.

[image]

[image]

This is the initial table:
[image]

This is the M Code:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="PayrollDates"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Start Date", type date}, {"End Date", type date}, {"Process Date", type date}, {"Pay Date", type date}}),
    #"Added Conditional Column" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "CurrentPayperiod", each if [Start Date] < DateTime.Date(DateTime.LocalNow()) and DateTime.Date(DateTime.LocalNow()) < [Process Date] and DateTime.Date(DateTime.LocalNow()) > [End Date] then true else null),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Added Conditional Column", each ([CurrentPayperiod] = true)),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Filtered Rows",{{"Start Date", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Start Date" = #"Changed Type1"{0}[Start Date]
in
    #"Start Date"
```

I have tried converting the final column in PQ to text, date, and whole number. It always comes back with the incorrect date once reference from the Excel formula.

Comment: according to the M code you posted, you're filtering the data, excluding some dates. Is that the cause of the differences? Did you check that the data model has the correct data?

Comment: With data in about the date range of your initial table, the M code returns no rows at all. Can you describe in plain words what you want to filter on?

Comment: Why would you expect them to be the same? The formulas are completely different.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld - I would expect them to be the same because the final result of the PQ is only the data I need. That PQ is loaded into the data model and the data model is referenced in the excel formula. So in my mind as I am loading the data from PQ into the data model and referencing the data model, the data output in Excel should be the same as the PQ results.

Comment: But your formula is referencing your. **initial table.**  No matter what your PQ routine does, your formula will still reference your **initial table**

Comment: @RonRosenfeld - I did not realize the initial table is named the same as the PQ connection. How does one reference the final result of a PQ?

Comment: @OgreSasqwatch The default name will be the name of the Query. If the Query is named the same as the original table, a numeric discriminator will be appended (eg `originalName_1`.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Changed table name to tbl_PayrollDates, never saw anything with "_1" appended.  How do I get the single date that is in the final step of the PQ? I am not able to reference the PQ connection in a formula, and referencing it by the data model yields the incorrect result as it is looking at the entire initial table. Which makes no sense as when I view the data model, it only shows the expected result, the same as the final step in PQ. Why does the data model only show the final result of the PQ yet when I reference it in the MAX() function, it looks at the entire initial table?

Comment: you can't reference the data model from a worksheet formula. You can only interact with the Data Model via Pivot tables.

Comment: @OgreSasqwatch Because your formula is referencing the original table. How, and where, are you loading the results of your query? If you save it as a table, you can reference that new table by name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I found was that I could reference the final result of the PQ by loading the PQ to a DM, adding a measure to the DM (MIN in this case as I changed the M-Code), then reference the measure using the `CUBEVALUE` function in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Your Excel formula references the whole uynfiltered table and returns the maximum date from that whole table, including all columns.

Your Power Query filters the data in the Excel table, which returns only one row of data in the current pay period.

By definition, that result would be different.

Edit: you can't reference the data model from a worksheet formula. You can only interact with the Data Model via Pivot tables.

Comment: I understood it to be that my formula was referencing the data in the data model, loaded to the data model from the PQ. But I see what you are saying, that the MAX function is returning the largest date in the table. I missed that, so I will backstep a little and state what I am trying to do.

Comment: I have the initial table as previously listed. What I need to do is extract the current pay period start date for a report, thus the M-Code. The meat of it is if the StartDate < CurrentDate AND CurrentDate < ProcessDate AND Current Date > EndDate THEN return StartDate.


The StartDate is what shows on the final step of the PQ and the preview box of the Query in Excel and shows there is only one row.

Maybe it is just easier to ask how to insert just the returned value from a PQ into a spreadsheet.

Comment: you can't reference the data model from a worksheet formula. You can only interact with the Data Model via Pivot tables. I edite my answer accordingly. Even if you don't like it, it is the correct answer and you should accept it as such.